# Programmatic Screenshot of Video Layer with UIKit/UIGraphics

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently dealing with an issue associated to **`UIKit/UIGraphics`** in `Swift` (library also existed in ObjC UIKit/UIGraphics).

I am programmatically capturing a `UIView` to save it locally. The simple code goes like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // use image var
```

However, this code does not capture anything else on the screen like a video player. The video player ends up being a black frame and not rendering in the image context.

Native iOS **clearly** does this. You can screenshot video easily.

What's the solution here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which view are you rendering here? You should render the view whose contents you want to capture. If you want the whole screen you should use the current window.